# PostgreSQL replace on alias column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `names_table`, where the column `user_name` has value like "bob_marley" (separated by underscore).

On select I would like to add one more column `user_name_display` that would exclude "_" from the value.

As result to have "bob marley", "xxx xx", etc.

I try:

```
select  user_name, user_name as user_name_display, replace(user_name_display,'_',' ') from names_table;
```

but seems I can not use `user_name_display` alias in the repalce() function.

**Q:**
 What is the way to get a new column with values where with no "_" in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed cannot use an alias in the select list, but you can use the column original name like this:

```
select  user_name, user_name as user_name_display, replace(user_name ,'_',' ') as user_name_display2 from names_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use that alias, just use the column name:

```
select
    user_name,
    user_name as user_name_display,
    replace(user_name, '_', ' ')
from names_table;
```

Comment: wow. so fast. I Just figured this out, refreshed page and there are two answers. awesome :)